# Why does Brouwer choose time as the only *a priori* concept in intuitionism, and how the numbers are constructed under such interpretation

Tags: philosophy, constructive-mathematics

I recently read some materials about intuitionism in the philosophy of mathematics, such as *Intuitionism and Formalism* by Brouwer himself, and some relative interpretations, I *maybe* understand how he treats infinite sets as potential infinite, a procedure that constructs its elements, and why he rejects uncountable sets and treats them as other things (e.g. the *Choice Sequence* of real numbers) for this reason, but I don't understand why, in his paper, choose the time as the only a priori concept, and the so-called *"two-oneness"* he built upon this, particularly in the phrase:

> [...] This neo-intuitionism considers the falling apart of moments of life into quantitatively different parts, to be reunited only while remaining separated by time, as the fundamental phenomenon of the human intellect, passing by abstracting from its emotional content into the fundamental phenomenon of mathematical thinking, the intuition of the bare *two-oneness* [...]

and how he constructs the numbers (or in his quote the finite and smallest infinite ordinal number) using this.

To me, it seems like he is defining ordinal numbers by using the moments of time. I don't know whether my interpretation of this is correct or not, even if it's right, I still don't understand how he constructs numbers upon the *moments* of time, and the connection between *time* and the *Intuitionism*

Comment: Physical time is not a mathematical concept. At best, our human experience of time is a motivation to define mathematical objects such as finite ordinals in a rigorous way. Brouwer was not the only one to try to use time mathematically. For example, Hamilton wrote "On Algebra as the Science of Pure Time".

Comment: If time is just a motivation for how things like ordinals are constructed, then what does "This intuition of two-oneness, the basal intuition of mathematics, create not only the numbers one and two, but all finite ordinal numbers" mean, it seems like the numbers are created *using* this interpretation, how can the creation of ordinals be reduced from time? what kind of role do the "moments" play here?

Comment: As interesting as this topic is, it doesn't belong in the math stack, you'll get more answers in the philosophy stack.

Comment: Quite vague the "original" Brouwer's philosophy, based on Kant; see [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/brouwer/#Bri): "As did Kant, Brouwer founds mathematics on a pure intuition of time (but Brouwer rejects pure intuition of space)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brouwer is alluding to an intuitive idea that is inherently temporal. The only possible way of suggesting this to others is the use of analogy: It is like an unending line of domino blocks tipping over, or a walk toward the horizon with each step. What Brouwer frequently calls a "move of time" is analogous to one of the domino blocks hitting the ground, or the planting of one foot on the ground in front of the other at each moment. To Brouwer, repeating this as many times as one pleases and keeping each instance in memory while doing so is what constitutes counting. This kind of thinking is briefly displayed at the beginning of Brouwer's original 1907 dissertation, where he builds natural number arithmetic from the ground up.

As for *why* he chooses time, in short and as far as I understand it, he observes that the succession of sensations in time is the most he can pin down as a fixed part of our experience, and he contends that this is how the intellect organizes experiences in one's memory, making the (unmeasured) sense of time the only a priori intuition. This is to be contrasted with conventions of time measurement used in science and communication; and it is in contradistinction with Kant's time and *space,* as Brouwer thinks that no form of space as in any geometry can be a priori, since they are all derived as subsystems of projective geometry done through homogeneous coordinate *arithmetic,* which is really all borne by time in Brouwer's eyes. He talks about this in his 1909 *The Nature of Geometry.*

Comment: But won't this way of splitting time introduce some questions regarding to what extent and grain size should we split? If he chooses to split the time so that the "slices" of time build the experience of one's mind, then shouldn't there be a size of the "slices" like, infinitesimal? so that the experience from those slices is gathered "one by one". I know this sounds really dumb and I don't have much background in philosophy but it's really hard to imagine how to split such a continuous concept of time down to the very detail. Or is this detail just irrelevant to this topic?

Comment: The issue with splitting time comes only when one is investigating the continuum—otherwise when we count, it's possible to understand it just as how it happens in daily life. The continuous, middle part of the twoity is already there *before* one imposes a grain upon it; this grain remains finite at every step. And no matter how finely grained, the adjacent parts of the grain still constitute a twoity with a continuous middle part. For this reason, despite many attempts to tackle it by various people, the continuum remains very elusive as a concept, even to this day. @Dylech30th

Comment: For "infinitesimal" slices, I recommend looking into smooth infinitesimal analysis. It provides a nice and consistent language and arithmetic for discussing that aspect of your question, at least your question as far as I understand it. In particular, the smooth infinitesimal continuum can be broken down into infinitesimally short straight lines, even if the continuum itself is curved, and these straight lines can be added up "one by one" through integration into the original continuum. @Dylech30th

Comment: Thank you! There was a second when I was thinking about resolving my question using analysis but I never really tried to do it, I will check your recommendation. @SpectreDNZ